# Fugacity vs compressibility

Tags: intermolecular-forces

What's the criterion for saying that the forces of attraction are dominant?

f < p or Z < 1

I ask this because there is a situation where

f < p and yet Z > 1 (below Boyle temperature)

if the criterion is fugacity, it is not so intuitive to say that the forces of attraction are dominant and the real gas has a molar volume greater than that of an ideal gas.

f: fugacity;
Z: compressibility factor;
p: pressure

Answer (score 6):

Let $\varphi=\frac{f}{p}$, where *f* is the fugacity, and *p* is the pressure.

Then:

$$\ln \varphi = \int_0^p \big( \frac{Z-1}{p} \big)dp $$

[Source for above expression: [Wikipedia article on fugacity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fugacity)]

Hence the fugacity coefficient, $\varphi$, at a certain $T$ and $p$, isn't determined by the compressiblity factor, $Z$, at that $T$ and $p$.  Instead, it's determined by integrating $Z$ with respect to $p$, at the given $T$, according to the above expression.

I.e., $\varphi$ is determined by all the values that $Z$ took on in bringing the gas up to the current pressure.  This makes sense, because it's directly related to the free energy of the gas.

Consider these three limiting cases, in which $Z$ has the specified value (or range of values) for the entire process (you should confirm these yourself, for your own understanding, by checking the above integral):

I. $Z=1 \implies \varphi=1$ ($f=p$)

II. $Z>1 \implies \varphi>1$  ($f>p$)

III. $Z<1 \implies \varphi<1$ ($f<p$)

*One can explain the result you are seeing as a case in which $Z<1$ for a sufficient part of the integration such that $ \varphi<1$ ($f<p$) but, at the specific pressure you are considering, $Z>1$*.

Physically, this means the following:

1. $Z>1$: Excluded volume effects dominate at the *current pressure*.
2. $\varphi<1$ ($f<p$): Attractive forces dominate over most of the range between $p=0$ and $p=\text{current pressure}$.

Comment: @ÉdersonD'MartinCosta  I added, at the end, a physical conclusion that corresponds to the mathematical conclusion.